# How would i create an array of object reference Variables?

Tags: java, arrays, variables, reference

So i'm working on a program in Java, and whenever i run it, i get an error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException". When i look at it closely, it appears that its caused by array of Reference Variables. Here's the code causing the problem:

```
    public class agendafunctions {
static String input = "true";
agendaitem item[] = new agendaitem[5];
public agendafunctions() {
    item[0].name = "one";
    item[1].name = "two";
    item[2].name = "three";
    item[3].name = "four";
    item[4].name = "five";
}
```

name is a variable in class agendaitem. From what i've read elsewhere, the error is caused by the program trying to use variables with a null value. But when i add a value, it says it can't convert from String or whatever to type agendaitem. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please stick to Java conventions and start class names with capital letters. Small letters are for variables and methods!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to instantiate those objects first. Declaring an array of objects just gives you an array of nulls. Trying to set properties on those nulls will give you a NullPointerException.

Before setting any names, you need to run:

```
for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++)
    item[i] = new agendaitem();
```

Also, you should change you class name to AgendaItem to observe proper Java style.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before you use them:

```
for(int i = 0; i< item.length; i++) {
    item[i] = new agendaitem();
}
```

When you create an array of an object, all of its values are null (primitives are the default primitive value). You must initialize each index manually (or through a loop) before using it.